# Trying to redirect users based on what they select in dropdown menu, having troubles inserting option into database and it’s not redirecting

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have been trying to solve this for the past week but no luck. What I would like to do is based off what role the user selects from the dropdown menu, they will be redirected to a different view of the site. Currently, the site is not redirecting based on user, which I thought the code from lines 65-78 on register_handler.php would take care of and the country the user picks is also not being stored in phpmyadmin. I have added/deleted or changed all the variables I could think of (including line 156 on register_handler, have included the picture below), but I just can’t figure it out to make it work. I know that most likely the error I am making has something to do with variables, but idk how to do it. Also, the code that I am trying to add is from this guide(http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-select.html/comment-page-1#comments). 
Thanks very much in advance!
Have included the code for both relevant pages.
Sorry if its messy, first time posting...

￼[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roxFA.png)

[Register screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh84O.png)
￼register_handler.php (added: ``,) for the new column in table named formCountry.
[Country selection form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kQFl.png)

Code I added in to the register.php

```
<?php  
require 'config/config.php';
require 'includes/form_handlers/register_handler.php';
require 'includes/form_handlers/login_handler.php';
?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Countries!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/register_style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <?php  

    if(isset($_POST['register_button'])) {
        echo '
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#first").hide();
            $("#second").show();
        });

        </script>

        ';
    }


    ?>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="login_box">

            <div class="login_header">
                <h1>Countries!</h1>
                Login or sign up below!
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="first">

                <form action="register.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="email" name="log_email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['log_email'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['log_email'];
                    } 
                    ?>" required>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="log_password" placeholder="Password">
                    <br>
                    <?php if(in_array("Email or password was incorrect<br>", $error_array)) echo  "Email or password was incorrect<br>"; ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
                    <br>
                    <a href="#" id="signup" class="signup">Need an account? Register here!</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="second">
                <form action="register.php" method="POST">
                    <label for='formCountry'>Select your country of residence</label><br>
                    <select>
                        <option value="">Select a country</option>
                        <option value="US">United States</option>
                        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="France">France</option>
                        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                    </select><br>
                    <input type="text" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['reg_fname'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['reg_fname'];
                    } 
                    ?>" required>
                    <br>
                    <?php if(in_array("Your first name must be between 2 and 25 characters<br>", $error_array)) echo "Your first name must be between 2 and 25 characters<br>"; ?>




                    <input type="text" name="reg_lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['reg_lname'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['reg_lname'];
                    } 
                    ?>" required>
                    <br>
                    <?php if(in_array("Your last name must be between 2 and 25 characters<br>", $error_array)) echo "Your last name must be between 2 and 25 characters<br>"; ?>

                    <input type="email" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['reg_email'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['reg_email'];
                    } 
                    ?>" required>
                    <br>

                    <input type="email" name="reg_email2" placeholder="Confirm Email" value="<?php 
                    if(isset($_SESSION['reg_email2'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['reg_email2'];
                    } 
                    ?>" required>
                    <br>
                    <?php if(in_array("Email already in use<br>", $error_array)) echo "Email already in use<br>"; 
                    else if(in_array("Invalid email format<br>", $error_array)) echo "Invalid email format<br>";
                    else if(in_array("Emails don't match<br>", $error_array)) echo "Emails don't match<br>"; ?>


                    <input type="password" name="reg_password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" name="reg_password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                    <br>
                    <?php if(in_array("Your passwords do not match<br>", $error_array)) echo "Your passwords do not match<br>"; 
                    else if(in_array("Your password can only contain english characters or numbers<br>", $error_array)) echo "Your password can only contain english characters or numbers<br>";
                    else if(in_array("Your password must be betwen 5 and 30 characters<br>", $error_array)) echo "Your password must be betwen 5 and 30 characters<br>"; ?>


                    <input type="submit" name="register_button" value="Register">
                    <br>

                    <?php if(in_array("<span style='color: #14C800;'>You're all set! Go ahead and login!</span><br>", $error_array)) echo "<span style='color: #14C800;'>You're all set! Go ahead and login!</span><br>"; ?>
                    <a href="#" id="signin" class="signin">Already have an account? Sign in here!</a>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
￼
```

Code I added into the register_handler.php

```
    <?php
//Declaring variables to prevent errors
$fname = ""; //First name
$lname = ""; //Last name
$em = ""; //email
$em2 = ""; //email 2
$password = ""; //password
$password2 = ""; //password 2
$date = ""; //Sign up date 
$error_array = array(); //Holds error messages

if(isset($_POST['register_button'])){

    //Registration form values

    //First name
    $fname = strip_tags($_POST['reg_fname']); //Remove html tags
    $fname = str_replace(' ', '', $fname); //remove spaces
    $fname = ucfirst(strtolower($fname)); //Uppercase first letter
    $_SESSION['reg_fname'] = $fname; //Stores first name into session variable

    //Last name
    $lname = strip_tags($_POST['reg_lname']); //Remove html tags
    $lname = str_replace(' ', '', $lname); //remove spaces
    $lname = ucfirst(strtolower($lname)); //Uppercase first letter
    $_SESSION['reg_lname'] = $lname; //Stores last name into session variable

    //email
    $em = strip_tags($_POST['reg_email']); //Remove html tags
    $em = str_replace(' ', '', $em); //remove spaces
    $em = ucfirst(strtolower($em)); //Uppercase first letter
    $_SESSION['reg_email'] = $em; //Stores email into session variable

    //email 2
    $em2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_email2']); //Remove html tags
    $em2 = str_replace(' ', '', $em2); //remove spaces
    $em2 = ucfirst(strtolower($em2)); //Uppercase first letter
    $_SESSION['reg_email2'] = $em2; //Stores email2 into session variable

    //Password
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password']); //Remove html tags
    $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password2']); //Remove html tags

    $date = date("Y-m-d"); //Current date


if(isset($_POST['formCountry']))
{
    $varCountry = $_POST['formCountry'];
    $errorMessage = "";

    if(empty($varCountry))
    {
        $errorMessage = "<li>You forgot to select a country!</li>";
    }

    if($errorMessage != "") 
    {
        echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
        echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
    }
    else 
    {

        $redir = "us.php";
        switch($varCountry)
        {
            case "US": $redir = "us.php"; break;
            case "UK": $redir = "uk.php"; break;
            case "France": $redir = "france.php"; break;
            case "Mexico": $redir = "mexico.php"; break;
            case "Russia": $redir = "russia.php"; break;
            case "Japan": $redir = "japan.php"; break;
            default: echo("Error!"); exit(); break;
        }
        echo "<script>location.href='$redir'</script>"; 

        exit();
    }
}

    if($em == $em2) {
        //Check if email is in valid format 
        if(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

            $em = filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

            //Check if email already exists 
            $e_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email='$em'");

            //Count the number of rows returned
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($e_check);

            if($num_rows > 0) {
                array_push($error_array, "Email already in use<br>");
            }

        }
        else {
            array_push($error_array, "Invalid email format<br>");
        }


    }
    else {
        array_push($error_array, "Emails don't match<br>");
    }


    if(strlen($fname) > 25 || strlen($fname) < 2) {
        array_push($error_array, "Your first name must be between 2 and 25 characters<br>");
    }

    if(strlen($lname) > 25 || strlen($lname) < 2) {
        array_push($error_array,  "Your last name must be between 2 and 25 characters<br>");
    }

    if($password != $password2) {
        array_push($error_array,  "Your passwords do not match<br>");
    }
    else {
        if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $password)) {
            array_push($error_array, "Your password can only contain english characters or numbers<br>");
        }
    }

    if(strlen($password > 30 || strlen($password) < 5)) {
        array_push($error_array, "Your password must be betwen 5 and 30 characters<br>");
    }


    if(empty($error_array)) {
        $password = md5($password); //Encrypt password before sending to database

        //Generate username by concatenating first name and last name
        $username = strtolower($fname . "_" . $lname);
        $check_username_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username='$username'");


        $i = 0; 
        //if username exists add number to username
        while(mysqli_num_rows($check_username_query) != 0) {
            $i++; //Add 1 to i
            $username = $username . "_" . $i;
            $check_username_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username='$username'");
        }

        //Profile picture assignment
        $rand = rand(1, 2); //Random number between 1 and 2

        if($rand == 1)
            $profile_pic = "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_deep_blue.png";
        else if($rand == 2)
            $profile_pic = "assets/images/profile_pics/defaults/head_emerald.png";


        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('', '', '$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$em', '$password', '$date', '$profile_pic', '0', '0', 'no', ',')");

        array_push($error_array, "<span style='color: #14C800;'>You're all set! Go ahead and login!</span><br>");

        //Clear session variables 
        $_SESSION['reg_fname'] = "";
        $_SESSION['reg_lname'] = "";
        $_SESSION['reg_email'] = "";
        $_SESSION['reg_email2'] = "";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<select>` tag in register.php you have to add an attribute name equal to "formCountry".

```
<select name="formCountry">
    <!-- Options -->
</select>
```

This is because on your server you're looking for data named "formCountry" (`$_POST['formCountry']`), so you need to define a name for this data also in your HTML (client), because if you don't that field will never be passed on the server because it has no name.

Read more about name attribute here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_name.asp